# Mulesoft doesn't read properties from right file?

Tags: maven, mule-studio

I had mavenize my project, trying to find the right way to handle DEV, Pre-Production and Production properties.
I created a property named mule.env, and added context property like

```
<context:property-placeholder location="${mule.env}.properties"/>
```

I have mule-app.properties and mule-deploy.properties, their content like below

> mule-app.properties

```
c3=c3.p1
c2=c2.p1
c1=c1.p1
mule.env=dev
```

> mule-deploy.properties

```
c4=c4.p2
c3=c3.p2
redeployment.enabled=true
c2=c2.p2
encoding=UTF-8
config.resources=test-config.xml
domain=default
```

I have a dev.properties under resources,

> dev.properties

```
c1=c1.dev
c2=c2.dev
c3=c3.dev
c4=c4.dev
```

And I have a flow to show properties in set payload

```
<flow name="test-configFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/"  doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <set-payload value="c1:${c1} &lt;br/&gt; c2:${c2} &lt;br/&gt; c3:${c3}  &lt;br/&gt; ${mule.env}" mimeType="text/html" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
</flow>
```

The result is

```
c1:c1.p1 
c2:c2.p1 
c3:c3.p1 
dev
```

I expect result like

```
c1:c1.dev
c2:c2.dev
c3:c3.dev
dev
```

since the properties should be from the dev.properties

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is obvious since in your `mule-app.properties` contains:

```
c3=c3.p1
c2=c2.p1
c1=c1.p1
mule.env=dev
```

this is overriding the value of `dev.properties` under resources
**Solution** : remove

```
c3=c3.p1
c2=c2.p1
c1=c1.p1
```

from `mule-app.properties`.  So, you `mule-app.properties` should **only contain**:

```
mule.env=dev
```

and no other values

Comment: So what is the order of the files? I thought mule-app is the default, and mule-deploy will override it. If mule-app override ${mule.env}.properties, where do I put default value for all envs?

Comment: `mule-app` is used to put the system variable and the values define there will override any values of properties file value under resources folder.  Since it is the one loaded first you need to keep only `${mule.env}` so that it selects the right properties file from resources folder like `dev.properties`, or `Production.properties` etc based on environment values that you give in `${mule.env}`.  So, you only need to put mule.`env=dev` or `env=Production`there .....You don't need to put anything on `mule-deploy.properties`

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Just one thing, if I want to add a default value for all environment, is there a place I can put it?

Comment: You can try something like this `${property.name:default}` example `${c3:c1.dev}` within mule flow in the code.. so that it takes the default value from there ... check this out https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/How-to-enable-property-placeholders-with-default-values